# How to get mediaplayer object which is in class extending service to another fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I have an activity in which i call service class through intent and pass uri to the service class ,in service class in onstartcommand() ,i get the uri and create mediaplayer object and play the song using mp.start(). In another fragment class,i use the intent and get the same uri which activity passes to service class ,and generate the mp object ,using this object ,i am able to get the getduration(),but i m not able to getCurrentposition() of the mediaplayer object which is playing in service class

MusicService.java

> ```
>          public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayerControl
>                    {
>                  public MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
>                        @Override
>                            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
>                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                               return null;
>                              }
>                           @Override
>      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags,int startId)                           {
>                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>        try{
>         Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
>         if(extras!=null)
>         {
>             if(mp.isPlaying())
>         {
>             String f=extras.getString("musicsrv");
>             Uri uri=Uri.parse(f);
>             mp.stop();
>             mp.release();
>                mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),uri);
>                  mp.start();
>                   }
>                  else
>                     {
>                     String f=extras.getString("musicsrv");
>                     Uri uri=Uri.parse(f);
>                       mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),uri);
>                        mp.start();
>                                 }
>                            }    
>                            }
>                            catch(Exception e0)
>                               {}              
>                              return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
>                          }
>                      @Override
>                         public boolean canPause() {
>                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                          return false;
>                              }}
> ```

Fragment.java

```
public class Fraggy extends Fragment  {
ImageView iv;
MusicService m;
TextView endpos,startpos;
SeekBar seekbar;
public MediaPlayer mp1;
private double startTime=0;

private double endTime=0;
private Handler myhandler=new Handler();;
private int forwardTime=5000;
private int backwardTime=5000;
int oneTimeOnly;
int c;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View myview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mainlayout,container,false);
    endpos=(TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    startpos=(TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    seekbar=(SeekBar) myview.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);



    Bundle extras1=getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras1!=null)
    {

        String d=extras1.getString("uri");
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(d);
        try {
            mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), uri);

            startTime=mp1.getCurrentPosition();// Here i m not able to get the current position
            if(oneTimeOnly==0)
            {
                seekbar.setMax((int) endTime);
                oneTimeOnly=1;
            }
            c=mp1.getDuration();//This works fine

            endpos.setText(String.format("%d min,%d sec",TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)c),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long)c)-TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)c))));
            startpos.setText(String.format("%d min,%d sec",TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)startTime),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long)startTime)-TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)startTime))));

            seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
            myhandler.postDelayed(upDateSong,100);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    TextView tv=(TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    Bundle extras=getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null)
    {
        String d=extras.getString("name");
        tv.setText(d);



        }

    }

    return myview;
}
private Runnable upDateSong=new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        startTime=mp1.getCurrentPosition();
        startpos.setText(String.format("%d min,%d sec",TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)startTime),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long)startTime)-TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)startTime))));
        seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
        myhandler.postDelayed(upDateSong,100);
    }
        }};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the same object what the service is now having,
Look for the binding the service to the activity,
[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html),
You can use the same object to both the place after binding the activity to the service.
And then you will be able to perform all the controls.

Comment: Can i bind service to fragment ? ,Thanks for the reply to my previous question,it is really helpful.

Comment: You can bind it from the activity, since it requires the context, and you can access it from the Fragment also. Since you can get the activity fields inside your fragment too.